# NullPointerException for bitmap image using Web Service

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

I am trying to capture image from camera or from gallery and save it to the php server (using my sql).I have attached my activity code and the layout and error log.I am getting NullPointerException for the bitmap when trying to pass to webservice.Image shows in image view properly only problem is when passing to webservice.

```
public class PhotoIntentActivity extends Activity {

    private static String MedicineURL = AppConfig.URL_MEDICINE;
    private ProgressDialog dialog;
    public Bitmap bitmap_cm;

    ImageView viewImage;
    Button btnUpload;
    Button btnSubmit; 
    Button btnCancel;

    TextView psttxtOcrResult;   

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.photo);
        btnUpload=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSelectPhoto);
        viewImage=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.viewImage);        
        btnSubmit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Submit);
        btnCancel = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCancel);
        psttxtOcrResult=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtOcrResult); 

        btnUpload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                selectImage();
            }
        });

        btnSubmit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dialog = ProgressDialog.show(PhotoIntentActivity.this, "Uploading",
                            "Please wait...", true);
                new ImageUploadTask().execute();

            }
        });

        btnCancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                viewImage.setImageResource(0);
                psttxtOcrResult.setText("");
                btnSubmit.setVisibility(View.GONE); 
            }
        });
        //..set visible false 
        btnSubmit.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        btnCancel.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        psttxtOcrResult.setVisibility(View.GONE);       
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds options to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

      private void selectImage() {

        final CharSequence[] options = { "Take Photo", "Choose from Gallery","Cancel" };

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(PhotoIntentActivity.this);
        builder.setTitle("Take Photo!");
        builder.setItems(options, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                if (options[item].equals("Take Photo"))
                {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                    File f = new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "temp.jpg");
                    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(f));
                    startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
                }
                else if (options[item].equals("Choose from Gallery"))
                {
                    Intent intent = new   Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                    startActivityForResult(intent, 2);
                    /*Intent intent = new Intent();
                    intent.setType("image/*");
                    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,
                            "Complete action using"), 2); */                   

                }
                else if (options[item].equals("Cancel")) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            }
        });
        builder.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == 1) {
                File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString());
                for (File temp : f.listFiles()) {
                    if (temp.getName().equals("temp.jpg")) {
                        f = temp;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                try {
                    Bitmap bitmap;
                    BitmapFactory.Options bitmapOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();

                    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(f.getAbsolutePath(),bitmapOptions); 
                    bitmap_cm=bitmap;

                    viewImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                    btnSubmit.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); 
                    btnCancel.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    String path = android.os.Environment
                            .getExternalStorageDirectory()
                            + File.separator
                            + "Phoenix" + File.separator + "default";
                    f.delete();
                    OutputStream outFile = null;
                    File file = new File(path, String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".jpg");                 

                    try {
                        outFile = new FileOutputStream(file);
                        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 85, outFile);
                        outFile.flush();
                        outFile.close();                                               

                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else if (requestCode == 2) {

                Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
                String[] filePath = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
                Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,filePath, null, null, null);
                c.moveToFirst();
                int columnIndex = c.getColumnIndex(filePath[0]);
                String picturePath = c.getString(columnIndex);
                c.close();
                Bitmap thumbnail = (BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));
                bitmap_cm=thumbnail;
                btnSubmit.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); 
                btnCancel.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                Log.w("path of image from gallery......******************.........", picturePath+"");
                viewImage.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);
            }
        }
    } 

    class ImageUploadTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... unsued) {
            try {
                HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(MedicineURL + "?tag=post_scan_img");

                MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);

                ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                bitmap_cm.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bos);
                byte[] data = bos.toByteArray();
                entity.addPart("returnformat", new StringBody("json"));
                entity.addPart("Photo", new ByteArrayBody(data,"myImage.jpg"));
                //entity.addPart("pharmacy", new StringBody(spinnerPharmacies.getSelectedItem().toString()));
                entity.addPart("pharmacy", new StringBody("walgreen"));

                httpPost.setEntity(entity);
                HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost,localContext);
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(
                                response.getEntity().getContent(), "UTF-8"));

                String sResponse = reader.readLine();
                return sResponse;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                if (dialog.isShowing())
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Log.e(e.getClass().getName(), e.getMessage(), e);
                return null;
            }
            // (null);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... unsued) {

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String sResponse) {
            try {
                if (dialog.isShowing())
                    dialog.dismiss();

                if (sResponse != null) {
                    JSONObject JResponse = new JSONObject(sResponse);
                    int success = JResponse.getInt("success");
                    String message = JResponse.getString("error");
                    if (success == 0) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), message,
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } else {

                        //caption.setText("");
                        psttxtOcrResult.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        JSONObject json_med = JResponse.getJSONObject("_out_put");                      

                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        e.getMessage(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Log.e(e.getClass().getName(), e.getMessage(), e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Layout is:

```
<ScrollView 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@color/bg_comn_dark"  >

<LinearLayout               
          android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:orientation="vertical"
           >

  <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    style="@style/HeaderStyle"
    android:text="@string/str_capt_cmi" />

  <View style="@style/Divider"/>

<Button
        android:id="@+id/btnSelectPhoto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="@style/ButtonStyle"
        android:text="Capture Now" 
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"  />  

 <ImageView 
    android:id="@+id/viewImage" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:padding ="5dp"
    />


<Button 
    android:id="@+id/Submit"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    style="@style/ButtonStyle"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dip"            
    android:text="@string/str_submit" />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnCancel"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
        style="@style/ButtonStyle"
        android:text="Cancel" />        


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtOcrResult"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"   
    android:padding ="10dp"    
     /> 

 </LinearLayout> 
 </ScrollView>
```

Error log:

```
07-14 11:51:15.316: E/java.lang.NullPointerException(1732): Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.graphics.Bitmap.compress(android.graphics.Bitmap$CompressFormat, int, java.io.OutputStream)' on a null object reference
07-14 11:51:15.316: E/java.lang.NullPointerException(1732): java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.graphics.Bitmap.compress(android.graphics.Bitmap$CompressFormat, int, java.io.OutputStream)' on a null object reference
07-14 11:51:15.316: E/java.lang.NullPointerException(1732):     at com.example.simplifimed.PhotoIntentActivity$ImageUploadTask.doInBackground(PhotoIntentActivity.java:224)
07-14 11:51:15.316: E/java.lang.NullPointerException(1732):     at com.example.simplifimed.PhotoIntentActivity$ImageUploadTask.doInBackground(PhotoIntentActivity.java:1)
07-14 11:51:15.316: E/java.lang.NullPointerException(1732):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:292)
07-14 11:51:15.316: E/java.lang.NullPointerException(1732):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
07-14 11:51:15.316: E/java.lang.NullPointerException(1732):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
07-14 11:51:15.316: E/java.lang.NullPointerException(1732):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
07-14 11:51:15.316: E/java.lang.NullPointerException(1732):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
07-14 11:51:15.316: E/java.lang.NullPointerException(1732):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Comment: Do you get the exception when using camera, gallery, or both?  Do you see the image in the view before you click on Submit and get the exception?

Comment: I trying with emulator avd so using gallery most of the times and yes it shows the image in the image view and when click on submit gets the error

Comment: I'm running your code on my phone and not able to recreate the problem.  I'll try on an emulator.

Comment: Please use a library like https://github.com/square/retrofit or at least OkHttp to make API calls.

Answer (score 0):

I copied the code you posted into an activity and commented out the statements related to posting the image and processing the JSON response.  I ran the activity on a KitKat device, selected pictures from the gallery and captured images using the camera.  I was unable to recreate the crash.

The stack trace indicates that when this statement executes in the background processing of your AsyncTask, `bitmap_cm` is null.

```
bitmap_cm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bos);
```

You indicated in your post and comments that when the crash occurs, the expected image was visible in the view.  I can't understand how this can happen.  I would expect when `bitmap_cm` is null, the imageView would be empty.

Note that `BitmapFactory.decodeFile()` will return null if it cannot decode the file.  You should check the result of that call and handle the failure case. Also add `Log` statements to report the status of your processing.

Answer (score 0):

Previously I was checking if there is problem with the coding itself when qbix is able to run same code without error..I have cleaned the project and rebuild all project and libraries again and it works fine.. thanks for the help of qbix